# AngularJS : how to avoid several calls to service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Let us say I have 4 views in my application . **Home, Product, Login, Upload**.

currently I am at Login View , after Login I am redirected to Product view.
Now for product view, I have a directive controller function something like below

```
function directiveController(){
 var self=this;
 init();

function init(){
 service.getProducts(parameter1, parameter2, successCallback, error);
}  

}
```

`service.getProducts()` will call the service and display the products. Now the problem is suppose I am at Upload view or any other view, and I am moving to again to **Product view** this service is getting calling again and again. I dont want it, I want once after login into the application this service should get called only one time and not every time.

I dont want to use `$rootScope` to implement this functionality any where in my application.

Any help, ideas, suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You don't want to call service or you don't want service to call remote api?

Comment: Why don't you call that in your login controller? Because anyways you are not attaching the returned value to the $scope. This is what I understood from your code.

Answer (score 2):

Have a sort of `factory/service` like `activeModel` which would hold the values for the `getProducts` api call, then you could check whether the activeModel holds some data, then you are not making the call.. else you would make the api call.

```
(function () {
    'use strict'

    angular.module('your-module')
        .factory('activeModel', activeModel);

    function activeModel(){

            var activeModel = {};    
            activeModel = {
                products   : {},                    
            };

            return activeModel;

     }
})();
```

Then inside your init method, you can check like this..

```
function init(){
 if(!Object.keys(activeModel.products).length > 0){
     //or you can check for some properties/values too here..
     service.getProducts(parameter1, parameter2, successCallback, error);
 }
}
```

Another simpler solution would be to move the api call to your `controller` by abstracting the api call to your `factory/service`.

Comment: thanks for your response, but I have a better way of doing this. Instead of storing data into service , I can store it using $state.current.data.products=array_value, and there by on page load I can check if($state.current.data.products){}.

Comment: @shreyansh: Yup you can do that way too which i feel is better than this as you don't end up creating another factory/service which holds bloats of information, but you did not mention you are using $stateProvider...

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Angular cache to store the data for a specific period of time: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory

This way you can implement your logic on how much you want or need this to be cached.

```
var cache = $cacheFactory('service-name-cache'),
    cacheKey = someSessionHash + elementKey,
    data = cache.get(cacheKey;

if (!data) {
   service.getProducts().success(function(result) {
      data = result;
      cache.put(cacheKey, data);
   });
```